# I need a SQL Query which group by employee with year,

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
select datepart(yyyy,hiredate) as Hire_Date_of_Year,jobTitle,count(jobTitle) as Number_Of_Title
from [AdventureWorks2012].[HumanResources].[Employee]
group by jobTitle,hiredate
having hiredate like '2004%'
order by jobtitle asc
```

### Above is my code.

the Output I am getting is this

```
Hire_Date_of_Year   jobTitle         number_of_Count
2004                Buyer               1
2004                Buyer               1
2004                Buyer               1
2004                Buyer               1
2004                Buyer               1
2004                Buyer               1
2004                Buyer               1
2004                Janitor             1
2004                Janitor             1
2004                Janitor             1
2004                Janitor             1
```

---

The Output I am looking for

```
Hire_Date_of_Year   jobTitle    number_of_Count
2004            Buyer               7
2004            Janitor             4
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really do date comparisons using `like`.  That is best used on strings.  Here is a way to write the query you want:

```
select datepart(yyyy, hiredate) as Hire_Date_of_Year,
       jobTitle, count(jobTitle) as Number_Of_Title
from [AdventureWorks2012].[HumanResources].[Employee]
where datepart(yyyy, hiredate) = 2004
group by jobTitle,  datepart(yyyy, hiredate)
order by jobtitle asc;
```

If you want, the `datepart(yyyy, hiredate)` (or `year(hiredate)` if you like) in the `group by` is optional.  If you don't include it, the `select` needs to put the year in an aggregation function, such as `max(datepart(yyyy, hiredate))`.

I moved the condition to the `where` clause for efficiency purposes.  You can do the comparison after the aggregation (i.e. in the `having` clause).  But that means the `group by` is grouping by all the years before doing the filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by the Year, not the full date

```
SELECT DatePart(yy, hiredate) As Hire_Date_of_Year
     , jobTitle
     , Count(jobTitle) As Number_Of_Title
FROM   [AdventureWorks2012].[HumanResources].[Employee]
WHERE  DatePart(yy, hiredate) = 2004
GROUP
    BY DatePart(yy, hiredate)
     , jobTitle
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by should be :

```
group by jobTitle,datepart(yyyy,hiredate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT jobTitle, Hire_Date_of_Year,SUM(number_of_Count)
FROM emp
GROUP BY jobTitle, Hire_Date_of_Year
```